# Installing Rails on Ubuntu 22.04: websocket-driver-0.7.5 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to install **rails** on **Ubuntu 22.04**, but fail as follows:

```
xxx@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
xxx@ubuntu:~$ ruby -v
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x86_64-linux]
xxx@ubuntu:~$ gem -v
3.4.10
xxx@ubuntu:~$ gem install rails
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/xxx/.gem/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5/ext/websocket-driver
/snap/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/xxx/.gem/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5/ext/websocket-driver
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230608-9473-4w3i5k sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230608-9473-4w3i5k clean
current directory: /home/xxx/.gem/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5/ext/websocket-driver
make DESTDIR\= sitearchdir\=./.gem.20230608-9473-4w3i5k sitelibdir\=./.gem.20230608-9473-4w3i5k
make failedNo such file or directory - make

Gem files will remain installed in /home/xxx/.gem/gems/websocket-driver-0.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/xxx/.gem/extensions/x86_64-linux/3.2.0/websocket-driver-0.7.5/gem_make.out
```

I must admit I am pretty lost here. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Thanks @Maxence, we are progressing?

```
xxx@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt install build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.35-0ubuntu3) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: This is not a very common error, and most SO questions are for Windows. I found this case though : https://github.com/faye/websocket-driver-ruby/issues/89 which recommends installing `build-essential` package that allows compiling C (Ruby is based on C). So this article may help : https://linuxhint.com/install-build-essential-ubuntu/

Comment: If it still doesn't work there are mosre cases : https://github.com/faye/websocket-driver-ruby/issues/86 but I hope you won't have to dig that far

Comment: Unfortunately I am not an ubuntu expert. Is your Ubuntu a fresh install ? Not too sure what creates this problem though there seem to be a fix : https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315906/unmet-dependencies-libc6-the-package-system-is-broken (installing libc6 explicitly) though I am not too sure about any problems it could cause to other packages or long term stability ..